# Transformation of force under different types Galilean transformations

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

Under simple boosts (one ref. frame $S'$ moving at a constant velocity $\mathbf{v}$ w.r.t. another frame $S$), why do we assume that the force vector doesn't change at all, i.e. $\mathbf{F}=\mathbf{F'}$? This isn't the same as how the position vector transforms.

On the other hand, for frames rotated w.r.t. each other by some angle $\phi$, we **do** assume that force transforms in the same way as the position vector, i.e.

$$F'_x=F_x\cos\phi+F_y\sin\phi\\F'_y=-F_x\sin\phi+F_y\cos\phi$$

I'm not able to wrap my head around this. Why does force remain constant across boosted reference frames and transform the same as position in case of rotated frames?

Comment: Because if a frame of reference moves at a constant velocity with respect to an inertial one, it is inertial as well

Comment: @user12986714: Thanks! But I'm not sure how that implies that $\mathbf{F}=\mathbf{F'}$ across boosted inertial frames.

Answer (score 0):

If you  change the reference frame, for example: $$\vec{r} \rightarrow \vec{r'} = \vec{r} + \vec{v} t,$$ with $ \vec{v}$ constant; notice that the time derivate of $\vec{v}$ is null and therefore the second derivative of $\vec{r}$, i.e. $\ddot{\vec{r}} = \vec{a} \propto \vec{F}$  is the same for both the initial and primed reference frames.

If the change is a rotation you must rotate all vectors simultaneously, that does not change their magnitude or the angles between them, it is a rigid rotation and therefore again both leave the physics unchanged.

Comment: Thanks! I think the reason I'm confused is that all we know for sure is that $\mathbf{a}$ and $m$ are invariant across inertial reference frames (IRFs), and **we can say nothing further unless we assume that force $\mathbf{F}$ is _defined_ as** mass times acceleration. But then if I do that, _even in a non-inertial frame $S''$_, I can define force in the same way and proclaim that $\mathbf{F''}=m\mathbf{a''}$ - I don't care how $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{a''}$ are related. With this proclamation I can say that Newton's 2nd law has the same form even in non-IRFs.

Comment: The only way around it seems to be that we shouldn't define force as mass times acceleration (specifically coordinate acceleration that Newton's 2nd law involves) in non-inertial frames. And in that case, we can no longer assert that $\mathbf{F''}=m\mathbf{a''}$, so we're good. What are your thoughts on it?

Comment: Indeed, when you use non inertial reference frames "fictitious" forces appear since  $\vec{v}$ changes with time in the above equation. Not so fictitious in terms of its effects: a hard break in a train causes major problems! The discussion of fictitious forces has great implications in the development of general relativity.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

according to NEWTON law :

$$m\vec{\ddot{R}}_S=\vec{F}\tag 1$$
and
$$m\vec{\ddot{R}}=\vec{F'}\tag 2$$
with 
$$\vec{R}=\begin{bmatrix}
   v\,t \\
   0 \\
 \end{bmatrix}+\vec{R}_{S'}$$

and $v$=constant

$\Rightarrow$ equation (2)

$$m\vec{\ddot{R}}_{S'}=\vec{F'}\tag 3$$

comparing  equation (1) with (3):

$\vec{F}\quad\text{equal}\quad\vec{F'}\quad$ only if $\quad \vec{\ddot{R}}_S\quad \text{equal}\quad \vec{\ddot{R}}_{S'}$

$\Rightarrow$

$$\vec{R}_S(t)=
  \vec{R}_{S'}(t)$$